# ACCESS SQL Datatype mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: sql-server

Have the following SQL

```
SELECT dbo_Members.Memberid 
FROM dbo_Members 
WHERE dbo_Members.Memberid = '10002'
```

dbo_Members.Memberid is a long integer and the 10002 is from a text box on a data entry screen that is a standard number.  I think the problem is in the where clause but can't see a datatype mismatch.
Let me know if further information is required.

Thanks
jpl

Comment: if memberID is a long int, why are you passing in a string 10002?  eliminate the apostrophes!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string when it is expecting an integer data type. If this is being manually ran, remove the single quotes. If you get the '10002' from somewhere as a string, cast/convert it to an int.